# Time Machine backups not available on MacOS Server

Tags: backup, time-machine, macos, server.app

I have an iMac running Sierra and MacOS Server, on which the Time Machine service is configured and running, with a folder configured for the Time Machine backups. The file sharing service is also running. But none of the Macs on the network (all of which also run Sierra), not even the iMac itself, can see it as a valid Time Machine destination in the Time Machine preferences pane -- it's not shown in the list of Time Machine backup disks. Does anyone have any suggestions for fixing this?

Comment: Can you connect to the intended Time Machine share--through Finder as you would for regular file access, not through the Time Machine preference pane--from those machines?

Comment: @Merlin Yes, I can use Finder to connect to any of the shared folders on the server, including the one that;s set up for Time Machine.

Comment: And having checked that, I tried Time Machine again, and it's working. I can't think of anything I've changed.

Comment: Hey, at least it's working! :-)